# div height auto adjust to loaded page content within

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my problem is I have a website I'm working on it has a main wrapper div for all the content then I have a div for the banner, right menu, middle, left menu, and the footer. the middle div named middle then has a div called content inside if it I'm using javascript to load pages into that div kinda like a iframe. when I load a page into that div I need the height to auto adjust to the content that was loaded into it. I spent hours and hours looking and trying ways to fix my problem but I haven't found a answer that works yet. so any help would be greatful

the main page coding

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Website Name</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function load_page(page){
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="' + page + '" style="width:600px;" ></object>';
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header></header>
        <div class="leftside">
            <div class="box">
                <h1>Menu</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li onclick="return load_page('php/home.php')">Home</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="middle" id="middle">
            <div id="content" class="content" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rightside">
        </div>
        <footer></footer>
    </div>

</body>
```

css coding

```
*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
list-style-type:none;
}
body {
 background-image: url("../img/bg/dark-forest.bmp");
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size:cover;
 font-family: "Verdana", Verdana, serif;
 color:#c3bdbd;
} 

.container{
width:1000px;
margin:10px auto; 
}

header{
Width:1000px;
height:200px;
background-color:purple;
display:block;
float:left;
}

.leftside{
width:200px;
min-height:1px;
display:block;
float:left;
margin-top:10px;
}

.middle{
width:600px;
height:auto;
display:block;
float:left;
margin-top:10px;
background-color:blue;
}

.content{
width:600px;
background-color:pink;
}

.rightside{
width:200px;
min-height:1px;
display:block;
float:right;
margin-top:10px;
}

footer{
width:1000px;
height:50px;
background-color:purple;
display:block;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: setting height to a % here doesn't give the real 100% height it only adjust for about 2/3 of the real height and vh does about the same depending on the amount.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would prefer that you change:

```
function load_page(page){
    $('#content').load(page);
}
```

Since you are already using jQuery anyways, why not fully use it's functions.

Add a container for the main content:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Website Name</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function load_page(page){
            // document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object         type="text/html" data="' + page + '" style="width:600px;" ></object>';
            $('#content').load(page);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
       <header></header>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="leftside">
                <div class="box">
                    <h1>Menu</h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li onclick="return load_page('php/home.php')">Home</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="middle" id="middle">
                <div id="content" class="content" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="rightside">
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer></footer>
    </div>
</body>
```

And also use flexbox:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
body {
    background-image: url("../img/bg/dark-forest.bmp");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: "Verdana", Verdana, serif;
    color: #c3bdbd;
}
.container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
.main {
    display: flex;
}
header {
    Width: 1000px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: purple;
    display: block;
}
.leftside {
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 1px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.middle {
    width: 600px;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.content {
    width: 600px;
    background-color: pink;
}
.rightside {
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 1px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
footer {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: purple;
    display: block;
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: this is pretty close the div is now loading to adjusted height of the loaded page inside of it but now the page layout is all destroyed going to see if I can fit it and thank you so far :)

Comment: Happy to help. If you want the original design, you can try taking out the background color for the middle class. Give the .content text color to be black and also the min-height for the .main to be 150px. The reason for taking our the float and using flex instead is because it is just more powerful, and it is so much easier to manipulate the structure of your page.

Comment: this does in fact fix my problem the layout problem I got after was do to me running a older version of firefox browser that doesn't support flex but after changing to a browser that does it works perfectly so thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following mark-up instead of directly specifying height:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    .box-centerside  {
      background:url("../images/greybox-center-bg1.jpg") repeat-x scroll center top transparent;
      float:left;
      overflow: hidden;
      min-height:100px;
      width:260px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box-centerside">
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
    This is sample content<br />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Specify the `min-height` for that div

Comment: no change didn't work for me try in the middle div, content div, and also the javascript function

Comment: overflow: hidden; try adding this also to that div and also add this property to your content div.

Comment: try the out come was the same just with out any h and v scroll bars

Answer (score 0):

Display flex, our new best friend

```
<div class="container">
    <header></header>
      <div class="middlezone">

    <div class="leftside">
        <div class="box">
            <h1>Menu</h1>
            <ul>
                <li onclick="return load_page('php/home.php')">Home</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle" id="middle">
        <div id="content" class="content" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightside">
    </div>
      </div><!-- /middlezone -->
    <footer></footer>
</div>


*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
list-style-type:none;
}
body {
 background-image: url("../img/bg/dark-forest.bmp");
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size:cover;
 font-family: "Verdana", Verdana, serif;
 color:#c3bdbd;
} 

.container{
width:1000px;
margin:10px auto; 
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
min-height:100vh;
}

header{
Width:1000px;
//height:200px;
flex:0 0 200px;
background-color:purple;
}

.middlezone {
    display:flex;
   flex:1 0 calc(100vh - (200px + 50px)) // container height minus header and footer height
}

.leftside{
//width:200px;
flex:0 0 200px;
min-height:calc(100vh - (200px + 50px));
}

.middle{
//width:600px;
flex:0 0 600px;
min-height:calc(100vh - (200px + 50px));
background-color:blue;
}

.content{
//width:600px;
flex:0 0 600px;
min-height:calc(100vh - (200px + 50px));
background-color:pink;
}

.rightside{
//width:200px;
flex:0 0 200px;
min-height:calc(100vh - (200px + 50px));
background-color:Ivory;
}

footer{
width:1000px;
//height:50px;
flex:0 0 50px;
background-color:Plum;
}
```

Be sure to run flex through this:
https://autoprefixer.github.io/

More info:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

https://jsfiddle.net/cmckay/ar8kL07z/

Feel free to put margins back in, I just simplified the code for the example.

Comment: page design change but after clicking the home button the div that the page loaded into was the same size as before no change in the height adjustments so it didn't work

Comment: how about now with heights set to min-height and flex grow set. - please see edits (both here and jsfiddle)